# JAVA how to write an exception if the user entered a number instead of a string?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Please explain I'm a little confused with do while .
If I enter the name of the city the first time, everything works correctly.But if I enter a number, I get a corresponding message, and when I try to enter the name of the city for the second time, it gives the same message.(about invalid data)

```
String town=scanner.nextLine();
boolean tryagain = false;

do {
        if (town.charAt(0) >= '0' && town.charAt(0) <= '9'){
            System.out.println("You probably entered an invalid data format");
            scanner.nextLine();
        tryagain = true;}
        else {
            tryagain = false;
        }           
    }while (tryagain);
```

I also tried the try and catch option, but I couldn't write an exception if the user entered numbers instead of a string.It doesn't work. Help please.

```
try {
    System.out.println("enter the name of the city");
    town = scanner.nextLine();
    
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    
    System.out.println ("You probably entered an invalid data format ");
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference between this line of code:

```
town = scanner.nextLine();
```

and this line of code:

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

They both accept input from the console, but only one of them stores that input in the `town` variable.  To update the `town` variable with the newly entered value, store that value in that variable:

```
town = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Wait a minute . For example, I entered a number and, accordingly, it was recorded in a variable (because it stands before do while).  why if I add a line town=scanner.nextLine(); in "else" block, the program will work incorrectly, but if i I add a line town=scanner.nextLine(); in "if" , it will work correctly (it turns out I'm saving an invalid value to a variable for me, but why does it work?)

Comment: @Vs_De_S: It's not really clear specifically what you're asking in that comment.  But, regardless of the higher-level program logic or what "works" vs. "doesn't work" means to you in this case... If you want to do anything with input from the user then you need to store that input somewhere.  Otherwise the code will just continue to use the same original value of `town`.  If that value doesn't change then the result of examining that value won't change.

Comment: What I have in the "IF" block is a bad case. The question was why if I write this line (town = scanner.nextLine(); )in the "IF" block, that is, I save the " bad " variable, then the program works correctly.I thought that the variable should be saved in the "ELSE"block, that is, in a good case, but for some reason this does not work and it confuses me.

Comment: @Vs_De_S: Because in your case the `if` block is checking for a "bad value".  When a "bad value" is found, you want to re-prompt for a new value.  The `else` block is executed when the value *isn't* "bad".  Why would you want to re-prompt for a new value if the user didn't enter a "bad value"?  The basic concept still remains... When you want to get a new value from the user, get a new value from the user.  When you *don't* want to get a new value from the user, *don't* get a new value from the user.

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, thank you, I just figured it out

Answer (score 0):

put it inside try block and try parsing it as Integer

```
   try{
             Integer.parseInt(town)
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
              //this is a string otherwise it would be number
    }
```

Comment: What is "Interger."?Where should I get this from? And what should be in the catch block?

Comment: if user entered string then only catch block will be executed

Comment: Interger is a typo. it should be Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Inside if block save scanner.nextLine() to town variable in order to check in the next iteration if it consists only from numbers or it is empty:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String town=scanner.nextLine();
    boolean tryagain;

    do {
        if (town.matches("[0-9]*")){
            System.out.println("You probably entered an invalid data format");
            town = scanner.nextLine();
            tryagain = true;}
        else {
            tryagain = false;
        }
    } while (tryagain);
```